# React Native delayed render

Tags: performance, react-native, render, bridge

Since there is a horrible issue in performance of react native apps,
can it be solved by delayed rendering of components in several events?

Consider an example,

I have an application which fetches data from an API and renders them in a flatlist. Each component in the flatlist has Touchable events.

Now the problem is the bridging done when scroll event occurs and we want to fetch more data from the API as soon we reach the end threshold value.

JS renders them into the RCTView but is also busy fetching data leading to UI freeze.

Can the last render be delayed until we encounter that JS thread is completely free? Or can there be a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are fetching data on the main thread and assuming that your data is complex enough that processing it can delay the UI thread, it's best to wait until the next repaint to fetch and process the data.

Use `requestAnimationFrame()` function to delay the execution of the data fetching part until the UI has finished execution.

```
let response = await fetch("https://emberall.com/user/1/recordings");
let recordingsJSON = await response.json();

function processRecording(recordingIndex) {
  if (recordingIndex < recordingsJSON.length) {
    mergeRecordingToLocalDatabase(recordings[recordingIndex]);
    requestAnimationFrame(() => processRecording(recordingIndex + 1));
  }
}
processRecording(0);
```

Example copied from  https://corbt.com/posts/2015/12/22/breaking-up-heavy-processing-in-react-native.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Take an example. I want to fetch Items from an API into a flatlist. I hit the API and I load the data into the flatlist. Now if I begin to scroll down fast, The touchables inside the flatlist freeze, because the thread is busy fetching data while the scrolling happens in the Native Realm.